# How to combine two lists together that are being formed while iterating another list?

Tags: python-2.7, list, scrapy, iteration

I'm using scrapy to iteratively scrape some data, and the data is being output as two lists through each iteration. I want to combine the two lists into one list at each iteration, so that in the end I will have one big list with many sublists(each sublist being the combination of the two lists created from each iteration)

That may be confusing so I will show my current output and code:

using Scrapy I"m iterating in the following way,

```
for i in response.css(''tr.insider....."):
    i.css(a.tab-link:text).extract() #creating the first list
    i.css('td::text').extract() #creating the second list
```

So the current output is something like this

```
[A,B,C]   #first iteration
[1,2,3]

[D,E,F] #second iteration
[4,5,6]

[G,H,I] #third iteration
[7,8,9]
```

Desired output is

```
[[A,B,C,1,2,3], [D,E,F,4,5,6],[G,H,I,7,8,9]]
```

I tried the following code but I'm getting a list of `None`.

```
x =[]

 for i in response.css(''tr.insider....."):
        x.append(i.css(a.tablink::text).extract().extend(i.css('td::text').extract()))
```

But the return is just

```
None
None 
None
None
None.....
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the order for each iteration important? If not, you can try `i.css(a.tab-link:text, td::text).extract()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm getting the following error, type error  `css() takes exactly two arguments three given`

Comment: This solution seems to work, which is similar the one you gave:

`i.css('a.tab-link:text, td::text').extract()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extend` function returns None, so you always append None to x.

For your purpose, I this is what you want:

`for i in response.css(''tr.insider....."):
     i.css('a.tab-link:text, td::text').extract()`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add two lists together and append them to your *results* list.

```
results = []
for i in response.css("tr.insider....."):
    first = i.css(a.tab-link:text).extract()
    second = i.css('td::text').extract()
    # combine both and append to results
    results.append(first + second)
print(results)
# e.g.: [[A,B,C,1,2,3], [D,E,F,4,5,6],[G,H,I,7,8,9]]
```

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks. I will check over the other answers written to see if there isn't a more concise solution.